# Amazon Web Services (AWS) API (1.6.2) - Simple Notifications Service - Add Endpoint

Tags: php, android, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have a basic Android app setup which registers itself to recieve push notifications through google.

I get the key and I store it which I can then use to manually add the device as an endpoint in the AWS control panel.

Now I would like to do the manual step in the background so I lookup the documentation and come to this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonSNS/subscribe

It looks like this requires the user to verify they want to be on the list but this is something to worry about later.

However, I can't make it work.
If I choose https as the protocol I get "Invalid parameter: Endpoint must match the specified protocol" which I am guessing means that the string I get back from Google isn't what it wants. I don't understand this because it works if I put it in manually. I have tried the sqs protocol but I suspect that I am trying the wrong method entirely - I just can't see another method that the API supplies that would do what I need.

I find the AWS documentation a bit rubbish (although I am aware it's an outdated API) and the their forums are nowhere near as proactive as the people on here. :)

Comment: Oh - just to clarify - the Android app is fine - it's the PHP bit that's supposed to communicate with AWS.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you  "subscribe" (or confirm) for mobile  push notifications... you "register." SNS really appears to be different services (or at least substantially different feature subsets) under one name: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePushPrereq.html

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question on the [AWS PHP Development forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=514138&#514138):

> SNS push notifications is a newer feature and is not a part of version 1 of the SDK. You should consider upgrading or seeing if it's feasible to use [version 2 of the SDK side-by-side with version 1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/side-by-side.html).
>
> I have an idea that you could try, but I haven't tested it myself, so I'm not sure if it will work. Try setting the $protocol parameter to "application" as described in the [version 2 API docs for subscribe()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html#_subscribe). Then set the $endpoint parameter to the "EndpointArn of a mobile app and device". Since the API version of the Amazon SNS service hasn't changed from version 1 of the SDK to version 2, there is a good chance that this might work.